# Alterar arquivo JSON no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, json

Eu tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
 <form method="POST">
   Title <input type="text" onchange="Function()">
   X <input type="text" onchange="Function()">
   Y <input type="text" onchange="Function()">

  /* others fields */

</form>
```

e o arquivo test.json

```
{
    "test":[    
        {
            "title" : "",
            "x" : "",
            "y" : ""        
        }   
    ]
}
```

Como faço para ao ter uma ação `onchange` nos inputs e o arquivo test.json ser alterado e salvo automaticamente no servidor?

Eu estou usando o PHP, então vou colocar o conteúdo do arquivo JSON em um array:

```
$jsondados = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondados,true);
```

Depois consigo acessar o array e colocar nas variáveis que quero.

Gostaria de sugestões/indicações de funções ou de como conseguir que o que for digitado no formulário seja automaticamente passado para as variáveis do php.

Comment: cada vez que o apertar uma tecla você vai fazer um submite para o servidor, é isso?

Comment: isso, mas atualizando o arquivo test.json, ou se não houver a necessidade do arquivo test.json uma outra forma de atualizar a variavel no php de acordo com o que for digitado no form

Comment: O JSON é usado como transporte, geralmente você grava os dados numa base de dados. Gravar o próprio JSON, só se for para estudo ou para alguma aplicação bem simples, com poucos dados.

Comment: são somente 3 campos é muito simples

Comment: fiz uma aplicação simples que gera imagem utilizando a biblioteca GD, e a variavel de texto, paddind x e y são os que devem ser preenchidas conforme o form

Answer (score 1):

Antes de lê o arquivo você tem que receber os dados do formulário em um *array* do PHP.

`$dados_do_formulario = array();`

`$dados_do_formulario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome_do_formulario'); /*eu uso esse modo que é igual ao $_POST mesmo, porque dá pra filtrar a variável depois se quiser*/`

Segundo de tudo, você tem que abrir o arquivo JSON e depois decodificá-lo como você está fazendo já.

```html
/* pego o arquivo JSON */

$arquivo_json = file_get_contents("test.json");

/* "transformo" temporariamente ele num array() que o PHP entenda*/
$decodifica_json = json_decode($arquivo_json);
```

Depois, você pode usar `array_push()` do PHP para incluir os dados do formulário no array do JSON (Eu estou usando uma inclusão simples como exemplo, mas antes de incluir, você pode pegar um índice existente e alterálo ou criar uma funcção para acessar o índice e excluí-lo, por exemplo).

```html
/* agora, usando o array_push() do PHP, você pode incluir dentro do arquivo JSON (que agora é o array() $decodifica_json) os dados do POST*/

array_push($decodifica_json, $dados_do_formulario);
```

Aí você tem que codificar o JSON novamente, quando tudo estiver feito e depois salvar o arquivo, usando `file_put_content()` ou uma sequência com `fwrite()` e `fclose()`.

```html
/* aqui codifico o array() do PHP em um formato JSON novamente */
$arquivo_json_alterado = json_encode($decodifica_json);

/* aqui eu salvo o arquivo laterado JSON*/
file_put_contents('test.json', $arquivo_json_alterado);
```

Comment: No caso não há necessidade de codificar (json_encode) um array no php para o JSON. O Processo que estou fazendo é inverso, nessa sequencia: Form HTML - > (javascript?) atualiza arquivo Json -> php decodifica Json -> pega as informações no array php e coloca nas respectivas variaveis $title, $x e $y

Comment: Se você quiser o arquivo salvo, depois de alterá-lo, será necessário codificá-lo novamente, senão o PHP vai salvar um `Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)`

Comment: então é impossivel mesmo, no lado cliente usando javascript  abrir e salvar o arquivo test.json no servidor?